# Save new data with Spring JPA - Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, spring, jpa

I'm learning Spring with JPA. I created a local DB with MySQL storing "Users", a web service with Spring and a front with angular.

I fed some data to my DB, and managed to display it with Angular. But the Post request coming from the Angular form does not seems to work. The form works well and provide an Object.

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utilisateur")
public class Utilisateur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;
```

DAOuser :

```
@Repository
public interface DAOutilisateur extends JpaRepository<Utilisateur, Integer> {
}
```

UserController :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

public class UtilisateurController {
    DAOutilisateur utilisateurDAO;
    @Autowired
    public UtilisateurController(final DAOutilisateur utilisateurDAO) {
        this.utilisateurDAO = utilisateurDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping({"/listeUtilisateur"})
    public List<Utilisateur> listUtilisateur(){
        System.out.println("Liste des utilisateurs");
        return utilisateurDAO.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/listeUtilisateur")
    void addUser(@RequestBody Utilisateur user) {
        System.out.println("ECHO");
        utilisateurDAO.save(user);
    }
}
```

TypeScript Fonction used in Angular to access the Post URL, User is an Object created via an Form:

```
public saveUserSpring(user: UserSpring) {
    return this.http.post<UserSpring>(this.userUrl, user);
}
```

Thank you for your Help !

Bertrand

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: No I dont. The data is displayed on the front, but when I try to add a new data, nothing happens. No Error, no data added in the DB :(

Comment: check your browser console do you have any errors? in browser's console in network tab check also if there is posted data to your server

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll check that asap !

Comment: you have subscribed saveUserSpring method or not?

Comment: Thank @RohitKavathekar, That was the issue indeed. POST method returns an Observable, so subscribe need !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
As  Rohit Kavathekar mentioned above, I didn't subscribed to the .post method in my angular project, which return an Observable and required to be subscribed.

Thank you.